# GA4 - filter internal traffic - issue

Tags: google-analytics, internals, traffic

I am the owner and admin of a ga4 property.
My goal is to exclude internal traffic from one or more IP addresses from reporting.
Into settings -> Stream I defined the internal traffic with internal value by inserting IP address.
After that in settings -> data settings -> data filter, I created a filter with value internal_traffic with parameter exclude. The problem is that it only works in test mode and not in active mode.
If I try to activate it, a small square appears in the center of the screen and it doesn't give me a chance to activate it. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and I found a workaround. Simply click on the arrow next to the filter to take you into the filter settings and click the activate from the list of radio buttons at the bottom of the screen. I tested my implementation and it is working as designed. I hope this helps